# How to display selected value from dropdown in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have state table having state_id and state_name. I am displaying it directly in template file like below..

```
  <select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2">
   <option  value="">Select state</option>
  <?php 
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $state_id=$row->state_id;
        $state_name=$row->state_name;
        echo '<option value='.$state_id.'>'.$state_name.'</option>';
    }
   ?>     
</select>
```

But when I want to edit that how do I show first selected state name.????

Edit page url...
    whitecode.in/demo/plotsup_plot/new-property/?listing_edit=6795

This is my function code in function.php file

```
   function getcity(){
      global $wpdb;
       if($_POST['state'])
            {
                $id=$_POST['state'];
                $property_id = $_GET['listing_edit']; 
                                     $district = get_post_meta($property_id, district, true);
                $result=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM districts WHERE state_id='$id'");
                //$wpdb->get_results($query);
                              foreach($result as $row) {
                                                             $city_name   = $row->district_name;
                             $city_id     = $row->district_id;
                        ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $city_id; ?>" <?php if($district == $city_id){ echo 
  'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $city_name; ?></option>
  <?php      
                              //echo '<option value="'.$city_id.'">'.$city_name.'</option>';


            }
   } 
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per as discussed in the previous comments, I guess that property is a custom post type in your site. So if that is the scenario then this should be the solution.

```
<select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2">
<option  value="">Select state</option>
<?php 
$property_id = $_GET['listing_edit']; //the PROPERTY_ID should be replaced with the original id might be ina get variable or any process by which you are using for the edit page.
$property_state = get_post_meta($property_id, META_KEY_STATE, true); //META_KEY_STATE is the meta_key name you use to store the value of the state in the postmeta table
$result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
foreach($result as $row) {
    $state_id=$row->state_id;
    $state_name=$row->state_name;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>" <?php if($property_state == $state_id){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>     
</select>
```

Try this and let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: property_id is my post_id. $state is my meta_key. But how do I get post_id?

Comment: could you post the url of the edit page here, then i could understand the way of getting the id.

Comment: check i have edited my code, now you should get the property id

Comment: Yes it's working ..now I want to show selected district just like state..and I did that using ajax and function called get_city which I wrote in functions.php

Comment: post the ajax function, will try to give you the modified code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61046/discussion-between-suvajit-and-kedar-b).

Comment: Suvajit see this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800727/how-to-display-selected-dropdown-value-when-user-edit-any-form and suggest some solution...I managed to pass post_id to ajax...

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you are looking for?

```
<select name="state"  id="state"  class="select-submit2">
   <option  value="">Select state</option>
   <?php 
    $result=$wpdb->get_results("select * from states");
    foreach($result as $row) {
         $state_id=$row->state_id;
         $state_name=$row->state_name;
         if($state_id == SELECTED_STATE_ID)
             echo '<option value='.$state_id.' selected>'.$state_name.'</option>';
         else
             echo '<option value='.$state_id.'>'.$state_name.'</option>';
     }
   ?>     
</select>
```

just replace SELECTED_STATE_ID with variable which contains which state is selected

Comment: that should work all you need to do is to replace SELECTED_STATE_ID with variable which contains ID of selected state

Comment: The above code is in my wordpress template file. So from where do I bring that variable which contains Id of selected state..

Comment: where are you storing the state id? is this a user registration form sate field or something like that?

Comment: Its a front end form for property registration where user register his property..

Comment: so what you basically want is after user has added his property for the first time and later returns to edit the property the state field should be selected, right?